# Get the key of a JavaPairRDD

Tags: apache-spark

I have a **JavaPairRDD < String, Iterable < Tuple2 < String, String>>>**

I printed it in a file and the content is

```
(ABC,[(ABC,1)])
(BBC,[(BBC,1)])
(CBD,[(CBD,1)])
(BBD,[(BBD,1)])
(ACD,[(ACD,1)])
```

Now I want to take only the strings ABC, BBC, CBD, BBD, ACD to a JavaRDD and print them in a file

Till now I am able to print them in a console using foreach

```
foreach(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String, Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>>>>() {

            @Override
            public void call(Tuple2<String, Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>>> t) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(t._1);
            }
        });
```

I want to do the same in a file. I am new to spark and so don't know how I could acheive this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try:

```
pairRdd.keys().coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("some_path");
```